# Atleast one field is mandatory in form: Form Validation in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have got three input fields on a form.
I am looking for a way in which a form is valid if either or any combination of inputs is required, It means atleast one is necessary .Also user may enter inputs in  any combination even then also form is valid.

I have read ng-required but that will make my expression too long.

```
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="name"
     ng-model="ctrl.orderSearch.name" minlength="4">
</td>
<td>Class</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="class"
     ng-model="ctrl.orderSearch.Class" minlength="6">
</td>
<td>Roll No:</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="rollNo"
     ng-model="ctrl.orderSearch.RollNo" minlength="6">
</td>
```

Update: I don't want to diable submit button. The form is valid in either of these scenarios:

1)field one or two or three is filled

2) 1,2 or 1,3 or 2,3 is filled

3) 1,2,3 is filled.

Also, I tried to use: 
ng-required="!(ctrl.orderSearch.name.length || ctrl.orderSearch.rollNo.length )" on fields. But when I submit my form ,an in built pop up from angular is presented on my name field saying "Please fill this required field" because whenever form.$valid is called on an empty form , field one would be checked first and hence pop up will be displayed on that field. But to user, it may seem field one is mandatory which is not the case.

Also , I don't want to write a custom method for validation. Is is it possible using ng-required? Please help.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Undoubtedly, I am new to angular js.

Comment: u can use novalidate in form element.

Comment: I used Ctrl+K , it formatted like that only.

Comment: Can u please create fiddle of your code..

Comment: @Anil how can I use non validate? Can you give sample code for that.

Comment: u can use in this way .. <form action="demo_form.asp" novalidate>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124528/discussion-between-anil-kumar-ram-and-shweta-gulati).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code check your code... check the fiddle link [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fA968/255/)
Hope this will help you to understand validation..

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <table ng-form="checkForm">
      <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" required  name="name"
               ng-model="ctrl.orderSearch.name" minlength="4" >

         </td>
         <td>
           <div ng-show="checkForm.name.$invalid">
               name error
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Class</td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" required name="class"
               ng-model="ctrl.orderSearch.Class"  minlength="6" >

         </td>
         <td>
           <div ng-show="checkForm.class.$invalid">
               class error
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Roll No:</td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-xs"  required name="rollNo"
               ng-model="ctrl.orderSearch.RollNo"  minlength="6" >

         </td>
         <td>
           <div ng-show="checkForm.rollNo.$invalid">
               Roll no error
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold; color:green">
          <span ng-show="checkForm.name.$valid || checkForm.class.$valid || checkForm.rollNo.$valid">Valid Form</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How will this help in soving my problem? Please explain

Comment: Basically what is your problem shweta... i ve explained validation part.. you can add or remove as per your requirement.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fA968/256/  created fiddle for you... Added save button which will be disabled if all 3 field is invalid, and will be valid if any of the 3 field is valid... Ab dekh lo shayad kuch kaam aaye

Comment: I don't want to diable submit button

Answer (score 6):

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ahL58/10/)

HTML

```
<form name="myForm">
            <input type="text" ng-model="fields.one" name="firstField" ng-required="!(fields.one.length || fields.two.length || fields.three.length)" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="secondField" ng-required="!(fields.one.length || fields.two.length || fields.three.length)" ng-model="fields.two" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="fields.three" name="thirdField" ng-required="!(fields.one.length || fields.two.length || fields.three.length)" />
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">Submit</button>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <p>Submitted ? <span ng-bind="fields.submitted"></span>

                </p>
                <p>Form $valid: <span ng-bind="myForm.$valid"></span>

                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Js

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fields = {
        one: '',
        two: '',
        three: '',
        submitted: 'Not Yet'
    };

    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.fields.submitted = "Yahooo";
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks , ur ng-required expression helped me.

Comment: simple but effective, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `$scope` variable that will do the "either or all of fields required checking". That `$scope` variable will be your flag on when a form is valid or not.

example:
**Controller**

```
function SampleController(){
    $scope.isValidForm = function(){ 
      //do the checking here.
      //return true or false
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
<button ng-disabled="!isValidForm()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to write a method or for that matter just don't want to diable submit button.

Comment: you can add ng-disabled="checkForm.name.$invalid && checkForm.class.$invalid && checkForm.rollNo.$invalid" to your button element

Comment: If you don't want to disable the button its up to you. It's just a sample to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code it will validate on form submitting event.It will restrict while you submit the form and your form contains all the fields empty.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { 

   $scope.isOneFieldRequired = function (name,uclass,rollNo) {
        return !(name|| uclass|| rollNo);
};
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form name="myForm">
             <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" ng-required="isOneFieldRequired(name,uclass,rollNo)" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="uclass" name="uclass" ng-required="isOneFieldRequired(name,uclass,rollNo)" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="rollNo" name="rollNo" ng-required="isOneFieldRequired(name,uclass,rollNo)" />
            <br/>
            <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```